# "Object variable not set" error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm trying to implement the following code, in which the code searches two worksheets for a specific cell and then selects the entire column - for it to be later included into a chart. My problem is that I keep receiving the following error:

> Run-time error '91':
>
> Object variable or With block variable not set

I have tried to look at various solutions on **SO** for the possible fixes for the error, but none of the solutions I have tried seem to work.

The error occurs on the line:

```
Sensor.EntireColumn.Select
```

I think the solution is very simple, but it seems a bit out of reach for me.

```
Sub Desperation()

  Dim Sensor As Range
  Dim RequiredSensor As String
  Dim SearchRange As Range

Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlToRight))

   'The RequiredSensor is a user input - What sensor the user wants to select
RequiredSensor = Worksheets("Home").Range("F18") 

 'Essentially, the code should search through DAQ 1 for the RequiredSensor. 
  Worksheets("DAQ 1").Activate
Set Sensor = SearchRange.Find(What:=RequiredSensor)

 'If it does not find the sensor, then it should search DAQ 2 for the RequiredSensor
If Sensor Is Nothing Then
  Worksheets("DAQ 2").Activate
  Sensor.EntireColumn.Select 
'Once the sensor has been found, it should select the entire column below it, ready to be put into a chart.

Else
  Sensor.EntireColumn.Select
End If

End Sub
```

Sometimes other solutions work for a few runs, and then they suddenly inexplicably fail again at the same point with the same error.

I included comments into the code to explain my line of thinking and what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You just need to check whether Sensor is a valid object or not so your solution should work...

Comment: Okay, so for some reason, Sensor is coming up as nothing. 'RequiredSensor' has a value and I think 'SearchRange' is working.

Comment: Your code is confusing. Please tell us what the intention of your code is so we can advise changes. Especially which worksheets are involved and what needs to be selected where when something is found (and where it needs to be found)

Comment: In Worksheet("Home").Range("F18"), the user puts in the name of a sensor. In worksheet("DAQ 1") and worksheet("DAQ 2"), there are two different databases with a number of sensors and a lot of test data underneath. What the code should do is looking at "F18", and find that sensor in either sheet DAQ 1 or DAQ 2. Once it finds the cell where that sensor is, it should select the entire column. I will eventually add a loop so that multiple sensors can be selected and a chart can be created.

Comment: There are two "Sensor.EntireColumn.Select" lines. In which one does the errro occur?

Comment: The error occurs in both lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently is saying "If sensor is nothing, then select it's entire column" which is impossible. If `Sensor` is nothing, then there's **Nothing** to select...

```
If Sensor Is Nothing Then
  Worksheets("DAQ 2").Activate
  Sensor.EntireColumn.Select '// <~~ sensor doesn't exist??
'Once the sensor has been found, it should select the entire column below it, ready to be put into a chart.

Else
  Sensor.EntireColumn.Select
End If
```

This is presumably because `RequiredSensor` hasn't been found:

```
Set Sensor = SearchRange.Find(What:=RequiredSensor)
'// If it isn't found, then Sensor isn't set
```

---

**Answer:**

One alternative is to simply let the user choose the range manually:

```
If Sensor Is Nothing Then
  Worksheets("DAQ 2").Activate
  Set Sensor = Application.InputBox("Select Required Sensor", Type:=8)
  Sensor.EntireColumn.Select 
'Once the sensor has been found, it should select the entire column below it, ready to be put into a chart.

Else
  Sensor.EntireColumn.Select
End If
```

Comment: If `Sensor` is nothing in `Worksheets("DAQ 1")`, then it should `Worksheets("DAQ 2").Activate` and check if the `Sensor` is equal to anything in that worksheet. If it is, it should select that entire column. Am I incorrect in this?

Comment: One you set a range in VBA it's a reference to a _single_ range - so if you set `Sensor` on "DAQ 1" then it **always** refers to that range on "DAQ 1" - you would need to set a separate range for any other sheets. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. The thing is, if the sensor IS available on "DAQ 1", I still get the same error. The code does not select the entire column. What am I missing then?

Comment: That means your `.Find()` method isn't actually finding the required sensor. There are a handful of options that you can use with the find method - and I suggest using them all explicitly because every time you use it (even from using Ctrl + F on a workbook) it saves the last used settings and will default to them in your code. You could be looking in formulas, for a partial match for example without realising

Comment: In the VBE, go to View -> Locals Window. Then step through your code using the F8 button and you will see if the `sensor` variable is _actually_ being set to anything

Comment: It says <Out of Context>

Comment: I've also just noticed that you set `SearchRange` to the `ActiveSheet` but then you change the activated sheet - so you're not searching on the sheet that you think you are

Comment: Aha, I played around with the SearchRange, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SensorSelecter()

 Dim Sensor As Range
 Dim SearchRange As Range
 Dim SearchRange2 As Range
 Dim RequiredSensor As String

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 RequiredSensor = Worksheets("Home").Range("F18").Value

 Worksheets("DAQ 1").Activate

 Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlToRight))
 Set Sensor = SearchRange.Find(What:=RequiredSensor)
 If Sensor Is Nothing Then

    Worksheets("DAQ 2").Activate
     Set SearchRange2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlToRight))
    Set Sensor = SearchRange2.Find(What:=RequiredSensor)
    Sensor.EntireColumn.Select
    Else

Sensor.EntireColumn.Select
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

As pointed out by @Macro Man, the issue was that `SearchRange` was not searching the correct worksheet.

Thank you @Macro Man

Comment: No problem - FWIW, it's always a good idea to explicitly state the sheet you wish to use instead of `ActiveSheet` and always fully qualify your `Range` objects with a sheet object.